# Xcode 9: can't convert float3 to int3

Tags: swift, xcode, simd, xcode9-beta

While trying to compile my project in Xcode 9, I get errors for conversions from `float3` to `int3`. The following line now fails to compile:

```
var max : int3 = vector_int(bounds.maxBounds * float3(1.0/8.0) + float3(1.0))
```

With the error:

`Use of unresolved identifier 'vector_int'`

So the old conversion function `vector_int` has gone away. The "fix it" suggestion doesn't work either.

`var max : int3 = vector_int3(bounds.maxBounds * float3(1.0/8.0) + float3(1.0))`

yields:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'vector_int3' with an argument list of type '(float3)'`

I can write my own little conversion functions, but surely there's a built-in way to do this, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector_int` has been replaced by `simd_int`:

```
var max : int3 = simd_int(bounds.maxBounds * float3(1.0/8.0) + float3(1.0))
```

Comment: To learn how to learn and be updated as quickly as possible I'm curious how did you found that out?

Comment: @Honey, I used sleuthing skills and luck.  I typed `vector_int3` into a Playground and option-clicked on it and saw: **typealias vector_int3 = simd_int3
Description 
A vector of three 32-bit signed (twos-complement) integers. This type is deprecated; you should use simd_int3 or simd::int3 instead.**  I then thought to try using `simd_int` in place of `vector_int` and it worked.